# generate valid JSON for highcharts on click

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

On click I'm trying to get a JSON formatted code in the allowed format 
        {
    customTooltip: 'Point 1',
    y: 45
}, {
    customTooltip: 'Point 2',
    y: 99
}

and add the series to my highchart like this

```
    $.getJSON("ntdc.php?test='yes'&vnr="+window.vnr+"&jmf="+jmf, function(data) {

    var MGD= data;
    console.log(MGD);
        chart.series[0].remove(true);
        chart.addSeries({
                        name: 'KB',
                        data: [MGD],
                        color: '#adadad'
                            });

});
```

In my JSON file "ntdc.php" Im generating the code like this:

```
    try{
foreach($database->connection->query("SELECT *, start as datum FROM $table $where ORDER BY start ASC") as $row) {
$volym .= "{y:{$row['volym']}, lpnr:'{$row['lpnr']}'},";
} 
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); } 
if(isset($_GET['test'])){ 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode(($volym), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
}
```

The data seems to be right and looks like this in console '{y:90000, lpnr:'97aDR'},{y:4749, lpnr:'96eDR'}'

Im not getting any errormessages but the chart is getting updated without content except for the new headlinename "KB"

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong or maybe a better solution? :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing the arraycreation in "ntdc.php" to:

```
    $row_array['y'] = $row['volym'];
$row_array['lpnr'] = $row['lpnr'];

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
```

and then removed the brackets (around MGD) in

```
    chart.addSeries({
                    name: 'KB',
                    data: MGD,
                    color: '#adadad'
                        });
```

and then it worked! :p